# How can you pass a function pointer and compare it in a function in C++?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, function-pointers

For testing reasons I have a certain number of methods whose signature in C++ would look like:

```
dvec3 (*)(dvec3, dvec3, double)
```

I put them in a vector as follows:

```
vector<dvec3 (*)(dvec3, dvec3, double)> methods = {lerp, plerp, splerp, ilerp};
```

The idea is to make a function that takes the function pointer and returns a string to identify the function that is currently being used (i.e I want to print out which function, among the 4 above, is being used)

For this I attempted to write the method as follows (I ommitted most cases on purpose):

```
string inline erpToString(dvec3 (*f)(dvec3, dvec3, double))
{
    if (f==lerp)
    {
        return "Lerp";
    }
}
```

The above however does not compile, the error message states that it's a casting error. What did I do wrong?

EDIT:

Compiler message:

```
/home/kronos/Desktop/OpenGL-Template/source/Rendering/rendering.cpp: In function ‘std::__cxx11::string erpToString(glm::dvec3* (*)(glm::dvec3, glm::dvec3, double))’:
/home/kronos/Desktop/OpenGL-Template/source/Rendering/rendering.cpp:1362:7: error: invalid operands of types ‘glm::dvec3* (*)(glm::dvec3, glm::dvec3, double) {aka glm::tvec3<double, (glm::precision)0>* (*)(glm::tvec3<double, (glm::precision)0>, glm::tvec3<double, (glm::precision)0>, double)}’ and ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to binary ‘operator==’
  if (f==lerp)
      ~^~~~~~
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/voxel-world.dir/build.make:111: CMakeFiles/voxel-world.dir/source/Rendering/rendering.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:68: CMakeFiles/voxel-world.dir/all] Error 2
```

EDIT:

I have made the minimum possible file that would have the same logic, however it does not reproduce the error:

```
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using namespace glm;

dvec3 lerp(dvec3 p1, dvec3 p2, double t)
{
    return (1-t)*p1+t*p2;
}

string inline erpToString(dvec3 (*f)(dvec3, dvec3, double))
{
    if (f==lerp)
    {
        return "Lerp";
    }
}

int main()
{

}
```

Playing around with the code shows the other methods (ilerp and company) do work. So it seems I have a namespace conflict (yay for using namespaces). SInce GLM defines a lerp function, but the one I need to use is the one I defined. Anyone got a suggestion?

Comment: Alternatively, you could just add logging to each of those methods; that way they'd help you keep track of which methods were called, and when, without needing to call your custom `erpToString()` function each time.

Comment: Seems like it should work. Could you post a [mcve]?

Comment: I just need to print the method being called to an csv file. I am evaluating certain properties of each method, all I want is each method as a title of the section of the csv file to be able to identify the data sets

Comment: You also might want to consider `__func__`, which contains a string identifying the currently running function: implementation-defined, though.

Comment: Maybe the function pointer should return a pointer? `glm::dvec3*`?

Comment: @wally definetly not, as you can see, the function signature of lerp is:
dvec3 (*)(dvec3, dvec3, double)

Comment: Well, compiler said you're trying to use function which returns pointer `glm::dvec3* (*)(glm::dvec3, glm::dvec3, double)`

Comment: The code posted doesn't match the error messages. May we have a [mcve] now?

Comment: @Makogan if two functions has the same name, same number of parameters but differ only by return type, you have a problem - this is violation of ODR, possible UB and really could cost you a lot of time debugging strange crashes and weird bugs. You'd better rename your own function to something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused because GLM defines a lerp Function as well, thus the compiler couldn't choose which function I was referring too.

The solution was, as suggested in the comments, renaming my function from `lerp` to `mlerp`

I guess this is a very good example as to why using namespaces is not a great idea.

Comment: Why does this mean that it's not a good idea to use namespaces? If your `lerp` is in a different namespace than GLM's function, they shouldn't conflict.

Comment: What is a bad idea is to add using namespace

In your code, since avoiding this kind of situation is exactly why namespaces exist to begin with

Answer (score 3):

You could use `using` or `typedef` to simplify all thing. Code works for me

```
int a(float x, float y, double z)
{
    return int(x + y + z);
}

int b(float x, float y, double z)
{
    return int(x - y - z);
}


using fdef = int(*)(float, float, double); // or typedef int (*fdef)(float, float, double);

std::vector<fdef> v{a, b};

if (v[0] == a)
    std::cout << "qqq\n";
```

Comment: "*use `using` to simplify all thing*" - or `typedef` in pre-C++11 compilers: `typdef int (*fdef)(float, float, double);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau definitely, but I encourage using of `using` any time I see  a need

Comment: I agree, I'm just saying not everyone is using a C++11 or later compiler, and the OP's question doesn't mention which version is actually being used. So just mentioning both possibilities, just in case, that's all

Comment: @RemyLebeau fair enough, editing the answer, thank you

Comment: It's a namespace conflict

Comment: @Makogan: what is a conflict? Please be more specific

Comment: I have a function named lerp, so does GLM. The compiler is finding GLMs lerp before mine when trying to compile that specific line. Since GLM defined it's LERP function differently than I did, my line of code is considered invalid and gcc terminates. The temporal solution is to rename lerp to mlerp, but I would like tyo know if I can resolve the namespace conflict rather than changing the name of the fnction.

Comment: @Makogan But how it was inserted into the container in the first place? If I add another function `int* c(float x, float y, double z) ` in my example and try to put it into vector, compiler complained (and rightfully so)

Comment: @Makogan: The compiler doesn't find one before the other. It finds both, and cannot choose.

Answer (score 0):

The key is `‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’`

In particular, you have two `lerp` functions. That's generally allowed. In most contexts, C++ will figure out which one you want. For instance, when you call `lerp(arg1,arg2, arg3)`, C++ will do overload resolution with those three arguments. But in `f==lerp`, there are no three arguments for overload resolution. That is why C++ says "unresolved overload".

The solution is to cast `lerp` to the type of f: `if (f==static_cast<decltype(f)>(&lerp))`. The three arguments to use for overload resolution are those of `f`.

Comment: ` That's generally allowed` no, it is not, if functions differ only by return type. That would be violation of ODR, causing UB and receipt for disaster. `C++ will do overload resolution with those three arguments` as far as I can see, arguments are the same, there is nothing to resolve.

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux: "generally" means "unless there is a specific rule otherwise". You are correct that overloading does not involve the return type. that is why I put in that diclaimer. It is also why I consistently write about overloading on the arguments.

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux: As for the ODR violation, that would entirely not be the case if you define two functions with different return types in different namespaces. (in partciular, the `glm` namespace here).

Comment: But all your answer is revolving about overloading resolution - and it clearly won't apply here. As soon as there are same parameters in the same positions, overloading is out of the window

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux `lerp(dvec3, dvec3, double)` and `template<typename T> glm::lerp(T, T, T)` are distinct overloads. Even if there was also `glm::lerp(dvec3, dvec3, double)`, that's not a violation of ODR.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to how to fix the bug, but an answer to your attemp of giving a name of the method your are using.

I suggest you to use std::unordered_map to discriminate different functions.

```
std::unordered_map<void*, const char*> funcmap{4};

union cast_fptr {
    dvec3 (*)(dvec3, dvec3, double) fptr;
    void *void_ptr;
};
#define MAP_VAL(FUNC_NAME) std::pair<void*, const char*>{cast_fptr{.fptr = &FUNC_NAME}.void_ptr, #FUNC_NAME}
funcmap.insert({MAP_VAL(lerp), MAP_VAL(plerp), MAP_VAL(splerp), MAP_VAL(ilerp)});
#undef MAP_VAL

inline const char* erpToString(dvec3 (*f)(dvec3, dvec3, double)) noexcept {
    return funcmap[f];
}
```